# многократно определенный символ

Tags: c++, c++17, visual-studio-2019

Я бы не сказал, что я новичок в C++(17), но эта ошибка меня совсем ввела в ступор.
Я пишу для себя расширитель возможностей SFML, и создал для этого "Extension/SFML_Vector.hpp", в нём у меня содержатся шаблоны функций, например одна из них:

```
// Extension/SFML_Vector.hpp
template<typename T>
T scalarMultiplication(const sf::Vector2<T>& a, const sf::Vector2<T>& b) {
    return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y;
}
```

Но когда я пытаюсь в этом же файле определить просто функцию (не шаблон), мне компилятор выдаёт ошибку об многократном определённом символе (функции):

```
float vector2Length(const sf::Vector2f& a) {
    return sqrtf(a.x * a.x + a.y * a.y);
}
```

Скажите пожалуйста, почему компилятор не хочет это компилировать?

Comment: потому что у вас vector2Length будет определен в каждой единице трансляции. Если это ожидаемое поведение, то функция должна быть отмечена как `inline` функция

Comment: Потому что у вас определение в заголовочном файле, вы включаете его в несколько единиц трансляции => несколько определений

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что в заголовочном файле вы дали **определение** обычной функции, что привело к созданию ее кода в каждом файле реализации, куда включен этот заголовочный файл.

Варианты решения:

1. Добавьте ключевое слово `inline` к определению функции.
2. Оставьте в заголовочном файле только объявление, а определение вынесите в файл реализации (.cpp-файл).

Comment: У меня вначале библиотеки написано #pragma once, что должно гарантировать только одно включение библиотеки

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ) Первый способ помог

Comment: Ну, тогда ставьте псису :) Да, второй способ тоже вполне помог бы, именно он использовался до того, как появилась возможность `inline`... И еще -  `#pragma once` гарантирует одно включение **в один cpp-файл**, но не один раз в проекте :)